# Updating to iOS 8.1 from computer

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

I want to update my iPhone 5s which now has iOS 7.1 to iOS 8.1.

My question is: If I update it from iTunes is the 5.1 gb iOS 8 going to remain on my computer or it will be deleted after the update is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS software updates are stored in `~/Library/iTunes`. If it remains there after the upgrade you can easily delete it yourself.

Comment: Also, iOS 8.1 is not 5.1GB in size. It's about 2GB.